# How to overwrite String in loop

Tags: java, string

```
public static String decrypt(final String encryptedText, final int n) {


    char [] chars;
    String s = encryptedText;
    String s1 = "";
    int buffer = 0;
    int buffer2 = 1;

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (j < 1){
            chars = s.toCharArray();
        }else{
            chars = s1.toCharArray();
        }
        char [] charsUpdate = new char[chars.length];

        for (int i = chars.length / 2; i < chars.length; i++) {
            if (buffer % 2 == 0 && buffer <= charsUpdate.length){
                charsUpdate[buffer] = chars[i];
            }
            buffer += 2;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length / 2 ; i++) {
            if (buffer2 % 2 != 0 && buffer2 < charsUpdate.length){
                charsUpdate[buffer2] = chars[i];
            }
            buffer2 += 2;
        }
        s = "";
        s1 = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < charsUpdate.length; i++) {
            s = s + charsUpdate[i];
        }
        s1 = s;
    }
    return s;
```

Hi, community. I have some problem here. I try to resolve some task and have stuck in moment when I need to overwrite my String in loop. I need give my old String in start of loop and overwrite this String in end of loop and give new String to start of loop, something like that, but I can't do this, because after first iteration in the start of loop I can see my empty String. Sorry for my shit-code and bad english :)

Comment: Do you mean in your final loop? S should be the concatenation of charsUpdate. If would be easier to just use 'String s = new String(charsUpdate);'

Comment: You get empty string after the first iteration because of the `if` statement in which you re-read `chars = s1.toCharArray();` and `s1` is an empty string

Comment: I changed my code, but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some other issues:

1. `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because the condition `buffer <= charsUpdate.length` is incorrect
2. Variables `buffer` and `buffer2` are not reset at the end of the loop, so after recreation of `charUpdate` array during the 2nd and the following iteration the symbols are not copied from `chars` to `charUpdate`

Updated and refactored code may look as follows:

```
    public static String decrypt(final String encryptedText, final int n) {
        int len = encryptedText.length();
        int half = len / 2;
        String s = encryptedText;

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            char[] chars = s.toCharArray();

            char[] charsUpdate = new char[len];

            for (int i = half, even = 0; i < len && even < len; i++, even += 2) {
                charsUpdate[even] = chars[i];
            }
            for (int i = 0, odd = 1; i < half && odd < len; i++, odd += 2) {
                charsUpdate[odd] = chars[i];
            }
            s = new String(charsUpdate);
        }
        return s;
    }
```

But I am not sure that it produces valid results.

A simple test shows the following output:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println("abcdefgh (" + i + ") -> " + decrypt("abcdefgh", i));
}
```

output:

```
abcdefgh (1) -> eafbgchd
abcdefgh (2) -> gecahfdb
abcdefgh (3) -> hgfedcba
abcdefgh (4) -> dhcgbfae
----
// for odd length of the input string
abcdefg (1) -> daebfcg
abcdefg (2) -> bdfaceg
abcdefg (3) -> abcdefg
abcdefg (4) -> daebfcg
```

Comment: You may want to check the refactored/improved version in the update.

Comment: Working correct, yes I was check yesterday, and close my task, thank you a lot